# How to return a concrete type from a generic Typescript function?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics, entity-component-system

I'm developing an Entity Component System and would like to be able to return the concrete type from my `get` function. Here is how I am currently doing it, which works, but doesn't have any type information:

```
enum CT { Null, Input, Transform, Physics } // CT = Component Type

class Component {
  type: CT;

  constructor(type: CT) { this.type = type; }
}

class PhysicsComponent extends Component {
  velocity: Vec2;
  
  constructor() { 
    super(CT.Physics); 

    this.velocity = new Vec2(0, 0);
  }
}

class Entity {
   components: Map<CT, Component>;

   get = (componentType: CT): any => {
     return this.components.get(componentType);
   }
}

let physics = entity.get(CT.Physics); // no type-safety since return type is any
```

I desire type-safety and code-completion, so I'd prefer if I could do something like this in the client-code:

```
let physics = entity.get<PhysicsComponent>();
```

But I'm not sure how to set up the library code to allow for something like that. For example, what would `components` be, and what would my get function look like? Something like..

```
components: Map<typeof Component, Component>;

get<T extends Component>(): T {
  return this.components.get(typeof T) as T;
}
```

? But that doesn't compile of course.

Also, I'm concerned about performance. Currently the `CT` enum is just numbers, so everything is very fast (and it needs to be, since querying is the most common operation in the game), and my intuition is that all these `typeof` calls, casting, and getting type information (which AFAIK is just calling `toString` on the entire class) are very slow operations, so I'm not even sure if this is a good idea despite the ergonomics, due to performance costs. Any advice?

Comment: Please consider modifying this code to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wEV4kN), clearly demonstrates your issue and does not have other issues (undeclared variables or types).  This would make it much easier for someone to give you an answer they can test before posting it, and that you can test after they post it.

Comment: Also note that TypeScript's static type system is [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) when TypeScript code is compiled to JavaScript.  Therefore, code like `get<T extends Component>(): T {...}` will compile to `get() { ... }` and thus there is absolutely no way something like `get<PhysicsComponent>()` would return something different from `get<InputComponent>()`.  Similarly, the `typeof` type query operator, "casting" with `as`, and getting type information, do not happen at runtime and have no impact on runtime performance.

Comment: Does something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mZ8QEw) work for you?  If so I can write up an answer; if not, please elaborate, preferably by producing a [mcve] I can work from.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz hey sorry for not creating a minimum reproducible example, but yours looks like exactly what I would make anyway, so that's good. I don't really understand how your answer works though. I think I might need an explanation. Are you saying that in the constructor of entity I need give it every component in the game, but they're all null? Because I currently have 100 components, and I'll soon likely have 200 more. So every new entity being created would have to run through those 100-300 lines of code, setting every component value to null? An entity doesn't have every component, only some

Comment: I'm happy to explain it but I don't know if I understand the use case.  If an entity only has some components, how do you expect `get()` to work?  Your example implied that it would always return a value (unless you're not using [`--strictNullChecks`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks); and if you're not you really should.)  Do you want it to maybe return `undefined` and you have to check for it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N7b5Bw)?  If you'd prefer that version I can write that one up, with the explanation of course.

Comment: @jcalz Sure, sorry for not being more clear. So basically in an ECS, when you call `get` on an entity, 99% of the time you already know it has those components. For example, you'll do something like this to get all entities in the scene that have a velocity and position component: `for (let entity of scene.query(CT.Velocity, CT.Position) { let vel = entity.get(CT.Velocity); let pos = entity.get(CT.Position); }` But yes, `get` _can_ return undefined, which is useful in some cases when you're testing to see if an entity has a component, and using it if it does. Does that make sense?

Comment: Also, is your most recent comment that mentions `Partial` the answer?? I'm not sure if I'm interpreting it properly, but it looks like it might fix everything? All I need to do is just fill in that `ComponentsMap` type with every component type and then I'll have the type-safety I desire?

Comment: Yes, `Partial<T>` is the same as type `T` except with all optional properties.  I will probably have to wait until tomorrow to post an answer; it's getting to be time for me to sleep here.

Comment: Sure! Hmm, one problem I'm having trying to implement it ... in your `get` function it's underlining `this.components[componentType]` in red saying `Type 'T' cannot be used to index type 'Partial<ComponentsMap>'` Any idea why it might be saying that?

Comment: Oh wait I figured it out, it's because I needed to include every single `CT` mapping in `ComponentsMap`. Okay so now I'm not getting any errors but for some reason I still don't have code-completion.. Hmm..

Comment: Ah actually I'm not sure if this will work. For example, if two different components both have a property named `variant`, then this line `entity.components[component.type] = component;` will give the error: `Type 'Component' is not assignable to type 'never' because the intersection was reduced to 'never' because property 'variant' has conflicting types in some constituents`

Comment: Is the scope of your question expanding because you got past the first hurdle?  If so, then you should edit the question to spell out what would constitute an acceptable answer, ideally with a [mcve] of what needs to work.  If not, then I'll just answer the question as asked and if you have follow-up questions you can post them separately.

Comment: @jcalz I wouldn't say it's expanding, no. Just that the solution with `Partial` doesn't seem to work because if you have two separate concrete sub-classes that happen to have the same member variable, then the `Partial` solution doesn't work. I'm still just looking for a solution to the original question.

Comment: I’m going to have to disengage soon, unfortunately. If my solution does not work, could you edit your question code into a [mcve] that shows what specifically needs to work?  If you are having trouble *setting* components and not *getting* them, I’d expect to see that as part of the example code.  Otherwise I’m concerned about scope creep.